# How can I record a video (and use the mic) and play an audio file at the same time ? iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation

I'm developing an iOS application, and one of the features that I'm trying to achieve is to record a video (and also capture the sound using the mic) and play an audio file at the same time, lets say to record someone dancing and play music at the same time, the output would be the video recording with audio captured from the video (footsteps or any noise) not the original played audio.

Any idea how we can achieve this? I found a way to capture the video while playing the music but I cannot use the Mic (It is essential in our case).

Thank you.

Comment: You mean you need to cancel the music from the recording?